# How to start count down from given DateTime to 24 hours with flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, timer, countdown

I have current DateTime, & want to start countdown till the 24 hours,
even if i logged out from the application, should still be continuing their countDown.

here the current Datetime

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.now();
 String currentDateTime =DateFormat('kk:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy').format(now);
 print("Current Date time: $currentDateTime");
```

Comment: it may helps https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch

Comment: Thanks but I already resolved my solution via [countdown](https://pub.dev/packages/countdown)

Answer (score 1):

finally, I found the solution from [countdown](https://pub.dev/packages/countdown) plugin
which is similar to my question.

code

```
void startCountDown(){

//  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
//  String currentDateTime =DateFormat('kk:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy').format(now);
//  print("Current Date time: $currentDateTime");
    CountDown cd = CountDown(Duration(hours: 24));
      var sub = cd.stream.listen(null);

      sub.onData((Duration d) {
          print(d);
      });

      sub.onDone(() async{
          print("done");
       });

      /// the countdown will have 500ms delay
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 4000), () {
          sub.pause();
      });
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 4500), () {
          sub.resume();
      });
  }
```